# Is there an online tool that can calculate advantage/disadvantage versus arbitrary dice probability?

Tags: dnd-5e, tools, statistics, online-resources

A variety of questions on RPG StackExchange fit the pattern of asking questions around the probabilities of advantage or disadvantage with or without a bonus versus x number of dice with or without a bonus.

Some of the answers give links to reproduce the results as R code on Github or other scripting languages that must be installed and hosted. We have searched the web on multiple occasions but have been unable to find something like a simple javascript tool on a webpage that can be used freely.

We have considered coding one ourself, but before doing that it seems prudent to ask is there any online web based tool that allows you to see the probabilities of advantage or disadvantage with or without bonuses against an arbitrary collection of dice also with or without bonuses? Ideally, the results would include a graph.

Please note: We are not looking for a recommendation of the best, or a discussion of which is the best, but rather, simply whether such an online resource even exists. Additionally - we are not looking for broad solutions - but this single, exact scenario described.

Addendum:
Regarding AnyDice - it appears it will require programming to get it to recognize the concept of Advantage and Disadvantage. If anyone has preconfigured, programmed examples for AnyDice to meet the scenario described above - please link to them.

Comment: I've flagged it as too broad because, while I do consider this a useful resource, I don't feel like it belongs to RPG.se, since, as you mentioned, there is no way (that isn't opinion-based) to get to any kind of "best answer" on this question.

Comment: Software requests are off topic at RPG.se, but can be asked at [softwarerecs.se] SE. (Pay special attention to their help pages on how to write requests that have complete information.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 9):

The most widely used is [AnyDice](http://anydice.com/).

It has options for most situations that come up with dice: rolling multiple, taking the highest value, counting dice rolling above a threshold and others.
Its main output is a histogram showing you an estimate of the probabilities of rolling each possible number.

Comment: It may be worth noting that though anydice is relatively flexible and can do fairly complicated dice mechanics, it has a significant drawback in that it will not handle programs that take the server more than a few seconds to run, which tends to rule out any complex inspection of large dice pools. However, the examples given in the question are simple cases it can handle very easily.

Comment: It appears AnyDice will require programming to get it to recognize the concept of Advantage and Disadvantage. If anyone has preconfigured, programmed examples for AnyDice for the scenario described - please link to them.

Comment: @Praxiteles It doesn't. It has the functions Highest X number of dice and Lowest X number of dice. Advantage and disadvantage are just a particular case in which X = 1.

Comment: @Praxiteles you should read Anydice's documentation. Specifically, it has two built-in functions which happen to describe how advantage and disadvantage work: [highest X of YdZ] and [lowest X of YdZ]. So, "output [highest 1 of 2d20]" will give you a roll which describes making a d20 check with advantage. If you were considering writing your own web tool hopefully you're able to work out the inverse.